# Why is median the solution to absolute difference, but mean is the solution to squared difference?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, median, loss-functions

What is the value of $a$ and $b$ that minimizes the $L_1$ and $L_2$ norm, respectively?
$$
 \min_{a} \mathrm{E}
 \left| X - a \right|
$$
I was told that median is the solution. How do you solve it? Why can't it be the mean instead?

$$\mathrm{E} (X - b) ^ 2$$
I was told that mean $\mu$ is the solution to the squared error. How do you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Loss: $$L_1(\hat y,y)=|\hat y-y|$$

Suppose that $$\hat y=y+\varepsilon,$$
where the probability density of error $\varepsilon$ is $f(\varepsilon)$.

Now, we can solve the problem $$\min_{\hat y} E[L_1(\hat y,y)]$$ using first order condition (FOC):
$$\partial/\partial\hat y E[L_1(\hat y,y)]=0$$
$$\partial/\partial\hat y E[L_1(\hat y,y)]=
 E[\partial/\partial\hat y |\hat y-y|]=
\int_{-\infty}^{\hat y-y}f(e)de-\int_{\hat y-y}^{\infty}f(e)de
=F(\hat y-y)-(1-F(\hat y-y))=2F(\hat y-y)-1=0$$
Where $F(.)$ is the cumulative distribution function.
Also I substituted $\hat y-y$ with $e$ in the integrals.

You can see that the FOC is satisfied when $F(\hat y-y)=1/2$, i.e. when the $\hat y$ is at the median of the distribution.

You can do the same for $L_2$ to show that it requires the mean.
Loss: $$L_2(\hat y,y)=(\hat y-y)^2$$

Suppose that $$\hat y=y+\varepsilon,$$
where the probability density of error $\varepsilon$ is $f(\varepsilon)$.

Now, we can solve the problem $$\min_{\hat y} E[L_2(\hat y,y)]$$ using first order condition (FOC):
$$\partial/\partial\hat y E[L_2(\hat y,y)]=0$$
$$\partial/\partial\hat y E[L_2(\hat y,y)]=
 E[\partial/\partial\hat y (\hat y-y)^2]=
 E[2 (\hat y-y)]=
2 (\hat y-E[y])]=0$$

You can see that the FOC is satisfied when $\hat y=E[y]$, i.e. when the $\hat y$ is at the mean of the distribution.

Comment: Is there a course I can learn this technique? This is pretty cool. I’m taking a probability course using Casella and Berger textbook. But, the book example do not cover this.

Comment: This type of stuff is taught in forecasting courses but all you need to know is how to setup the problem. The rest is a simple calculus. I'll update the answer with a link to a book or paper later

Comment: [Granger's paper](https://books.google.com/books?id=RskN3Db7MlgC&lpg=PA8&ots=qxxAtbERjf&dq=forecasting%20granger%20cost&pg=PA366#v=onepage&q=forecasting%20granger%20cost&f=false) is a good intro into how cost function are used in forecasting to come up with optimal forecasts, he has example for quadratic loss (cost) leading to the mean

Comment: Can you explain why the middle number minimizes the absolute difference? Why not the mean?

Comment: @user13985 $F(x)=1/2$ is a definition of the median, i.e. when the probability below and above x is the same 50%. For symmetrical distributions such as Gaussian, median and mean are the same

Comment: That makes sense. But doesn't mean make more sense than median? Just wondering. Definition of median in wikipedia $P(X \le m) = \frac{1}{2} = P(X \ge m) = \int f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}$ I need to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The squared error is the simpler case, and a classic argument, so I will reproduce it here.

Let $\mu = E[X]$.  Then we can use an add and subtract trick

$$ E[(X - b)^2] = E[(X - \mu + \mu - b)^2] = E[(X - \mu)^2] + 2 E[(X - \mu)(\mu - b)] + 2 E[(\mu - b)^2] $$

Now in the middle term, $\mu - b$ is a constant, so it can come outside of the expectation

$$ E[(X - \mu)(\mu - b)] = (\mu - b) E[X - \mu] = (\mu - b)(E[X] - \mu) = 0 $$

So, all together

$$ E[(X - b)^2] = E[(X - \mu)^2] + 2 E[(\mu - b)^2] $$

This is clearly minimized when $b = \mu$.

The median case is more elusive, but still elementary, and also deserving of classic status.  You can look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113270/the-median-minimizes-the-sum-of-absolute-deviations) for some proofs.  Both André's and Brian's answers are simple and intuitive demonstrations.

Comment: Solution in link is using ordered statistics to get the median. I read it. It was very long. I was completely lost when I reached the end.

Comment: Ok... That tends to happen with mathematics.  You should always anticipate that you will need to read something multiple times and maybe take a walk and think about it.  I think the idea there is simple and beautiful, but you are free to disagree!

Comment: Why does the median minimize the absolute difference? What's the intuition in simple words?

Comment: Im not sure there is an intuition in simple words for either case, why do you believe a simple reason exists?

Comment: I read this post. They used median to explain it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85448/why-does-the-median-minimize-ex-c

Comment: That's only a simple or intuitive explanation if calculus is simple and intuitive to you.  But, I'm glad you found one that you like!

Comment: Your L2 norm was explanation was pretty good, I must say!